# How to disable element / change styling upon another field change in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I have 2 fields:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" #quantity="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="orderProduct.selectedProduct.quantity" required min="1" max="50">
```

and a checkbox

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="orderProduct.selectedProduct.Option" value="{{option.Value}}" [(ngModel)]="option.checked" /> <!-- disable checkbox -->
    <span class="checkmark"></span> <!-- change css style to this element -->
</label>
```

How can I disable/ enable the checkbox and change the styling to `checkmark` element if a user inputs the incorrect/ correct range of values (between min and max) in the `quantity` field?

I'm new to angular and struggling to find solution. I'm using Angular 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `disabled` property in `<input>`. So, in `disabled` you can check the validity of your `<input type="text" name="quantity" ..` by using **`quantity.invalid`** like this:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="orderProduct.selectedProduct.Option" value="{{option.Value}}" [(ngModel)]="option.checked" disabled="quantity.invalid"/> <!-- disable checkbox -->
    <span class="checkmark"></span> <!-- change css style to this element -->
</label>
```

There's two option to check the validity (If you don't want to use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)):

1. Pass custom `validator` to the `<input>`. Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).
2. Use `ngModelChange` within `<input>` like `<input (ngModelChange)="isInputValid($event)" name="quantity" ..` and in your `.ts` file write this method to update a boolean (say `isquantityValid`) based on the validity of your input. Then use that variable to `enable\disable` the checkbox. [Read More](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel)

To change the style conditionally do something like this:

```
<span [ngClass]="isquantityValid ? 'styleClass1' : 'styleClass2'">content</span>
```

Comment: ok @noobs, I have `[disabled]="!myform.valid"` but how to change the span class and how to validate the range of the other field?

Comment: @nickornotto updated my answer. As your question contains many parts please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Great it worked @noobs, both for validation I used option 2) and styling. Thank you